# Bash find execute process with output redirected to a different file per each

Tags: bash, unix, makefile, terminal

I'd like to run the following bash command for every file in a folder (outputting a unique JSON file for each processed .csv), via a Makefile:

```
csvtojson ./file/path.csv > ./file/path.json
```

Here's what I've managed, I'm struggling with the stdin/out syntax and arguments:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" -exec csvtojson {} > {}.json \;
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: BTW, in general, using `{}` as a substring in `find -exec` is best avoided. [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) doesn't guarantee that that behavior will work, and many of the common use cases have significant security caveats (for instance, `sh -c 'mv {}/* ..'`  will treat anything in `$()` within a filename being processed as if it were code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only passing a single argument to `csvtojson` -- the filename to run.

The `> outputfile` isn't an argument at all; instead, it's an instruction to the shell that parses and invokes the relevant command to connect the command's stdout to the given filename before actually starting that command.

Thus, above, that redirection is parsed before the `find` command is run -- because that's the only place a shell is involved at all.

If you *want* to involve a shell, consider doing so as follows:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" \
  -exec sh -c 'for arg; do csvtojson "$arg" >"${arg}.json"; done' _ {} +
```

...or, as follows:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    csvtojson "$filename" >"$filename.json"
  done
```

...or, if you want to be able to set shell variables inside the loop and have them persist after its exit, you can use a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to avoid the issues described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024):

```
bad=0
good=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  if csvtojson "$filename" >"$filename.json"; then
    (( ++good ))
  else
    (( ++bad ))
  fi
done < <(find ./ -type f -name '*.csv' -print0)

echo "Converting CSV files to JSON: ${bad} failures, ${good} successes" >&2
```

---

See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), particularly the [Complex Actions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions) section and the section on [Actions In Bulk](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and references!

Comment: No problem! I was expecting we'd have a preexisting question on the subject already in the knowledge base, but a quick search only came up ones with unfortunate answers, sometimes driven by questions with unusual details or caveats. Thank you for writing a clean, answerable question on the subject. :)

Comment: Heh, no worries. I shall spend a little time with the manual and these 3 options now..